# Sql Query, not retrieving correct values with CURDATE() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve records from database where my 'dateOfTermination' value is equal to today's date. 
I used the below query, but it won't show any results.

```
select * from user 
where CRM_Status='pending' and dateOfTermination = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

It will only work if the query is as below.

```
select * from user 
where CRM_Status='pending' and dateOfTermination < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Is it because of an issue in date format?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Those queries are product specific.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's SQL Server

Comment: Please list the user table schema (column names and datatypes).

Comment: Field: dateOfTermination  
Data Type: varchar(100)

Comment: If you were u sing SQL Server, then the queries would be returning errors.  The syntax strongly suggests MySQL, so I tagged the question appropriately.

Comment: @sj111 what is the date format of dateOfTermination? Just give a sample value of dateOfTermination.

Comment: Sample value: 07/31/2017 (mm/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `dateOfTermination` has a time component.  Try this:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.CRM_Status = 'pending' and
      u.dateOfTermination >= CURDATE() AND
      u.dateOfTermination < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

You can also express this as:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.CRM_Status = 'pending' and
      DATE(u.dateOfTermination) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Actually, the semantics are slightly different -- but it is unclear what you really intend.  The first version is "better" in the sense that it can better make use of indexes for performance.

Comment: I tried what you have shared. Still I am facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL DATE_FORMAT function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/) to get the date without the time component and then do the comparison. So the query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE CRM_Status='pending' AND 
DATE_FORMAT(dateOfTermination,'%d-%m-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%d-%m-%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the time is the problem. Why not just keep it simple?

select * from user 
where CRM_Status='pending' 
and cast(dateOfTermination as date) = cast(GETDATE() as DATE)

Comment: select * from user where CRM_Status='pending' and cast(dateOfTermination as date) = cast(UTC_DATE() as DATE)                           

Still the same issue.

Comment: Random question. But looking at your initial data, you get results when you are looking at < but nothing when you are looking at = to today. Are there values where dateOfTermination are = to today?

Comment: Yes. there is. i have set the date of the record to today's date.
same record gets retrieved when the sign is '<' or '<='

But not with only the '=' sign

Comment: May i ask for example data of something like this:

Comment: select top 1 cast(dateOfTermination as date), cast(UTC_DATE() as DATE) from user